# How can i improve speed of generating 32bits random prime number?

Tags: c, cryptography, numbers, rsa

```
uint64_t prime_32bits(){
    uint64_t n = 0x40000000; // n = 2^30
    uint64_t ret = (uint64_t)arc4random_uniform(n) + n*3; // 2^31+2^30 <= ret < 2^32

    while(1){
        if(miller_rabin(ret)) break;
        ++ret;
        if(ret > 0xffffffff) ret = (uint64_t)arc4random_uniform(n) + n*3;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This is my code, generating 32bits random prime number.

But I want to improve speed of the algorithm.

How can I fix it?

Comment: If it's only prime numbers up to 32bits you could pregenerate all of them and keep them in a file. Then you would have instant lookup.

Comment: Given there are only 203,280,220 32-bit prime numbers you could put them in an array and select a random index into the array.....http://www.umopit.ru/CompLab/primes32eng.htm

Comment: @MitchWheat: That page says there are 203,280,220 odd primes less than 2^32, not  203,280,220 primes. But OP is interested only in those in the top quarter of the 32-bit range, of which there are 48,709,705, according to WolframAlpha.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil : there is only 1 even prime.

Comment: You could ensure you only have odd numbers in `ret` and use `ret += 2;` instead of `ret++;`.  All primes bigger than 3 have the form 6N+/-1 — you can use that to reduce the number of tests still further.  You could consider using simpler test than Miller-Rabin to eliminate many compound (non-prime) values with code that tests for prime factors from 3 to 97, for example.

Comment: Is it possible to generate only odd random numbers with arc4random_uniform function?

Comment: @hide if it's even, just subtract one. But if you are looking for speed look at the suggestions about pregenerated primes instead.

Comment: @hide with any random function: `myrandfunc() | 1`

Comment: The [PARI](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) number theory library has a `randomprime()` function that can generate a prime in a given range.

Comment: Or use openssl: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/BN_generate_prime_ex.html